# Animation in edit mode?

Tags: animation, shape-keys

So I want to animate from the segment you can see in the first picture to it being slightly morphed like in the second picture. I can't keyframe in edit mode it seems. I've tried keyframing it in object mode in the first picture at frame 0, changing to edit mode, moving the vertex to match the second picture, then going back to object mode at frame 10 and inserting a new keyframe. Unfortunately this does not work :( any suggestions?[image: s]

Comment: You have to add two shapekeys, one is the basis and the other is the morphed, then animate its value, so at 0th frame adjust Key1 to 0, move the mouse above the slider and hit "i". Go to 10th frame, set the slider to 1 then hit "i" again. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Zijo8ly6pyI